# .htaccess RewriteRule with pageparameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm finally asking my first question on Stackoverflow:

I'm creating a website which has the base template *(header, menu, footer)* as the index.php and all the content links will call the index.php with a parameter called '?page=asdf'. (I hope it's a reasonable strucutre for a business site.)

```
<div class="page_wrapper">
    <?php 
        if (isset($_GET['page'])){
                include 'tpl/'.$_GET['page'].'.php';    
        }
        else{
            include 'tpl/start.php';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Now i want to rewrite the urls without the .php at the end like 
**page.com/index.php?get=products** should be **page.com/products**.
The same for 'about', 'contact' and so on.
And the startpage should always be like page.com/

One of the important points is that it should be multilingual in English & German and I really don't know how to it. Do I have to make each Filename in German and English ?

I did it 2 years ago only with one language but I can't remind how I did it and lost the source code.

<=============================>

GOT IT:

I used **RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]**

Thanks @Jon Lin for the help, you brought me to this idea.

Comment: `include 'tpl/'.$_GET['page'].'.php';` - unless you filter that get arument - that's a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks, I see the logic behind but I doesn't work.
my .htaccess is being loaded I get ERR500 when i put rubbish in it..